Run ABAP Unit Tests Programmatically
How can we run ABAP Unit tests programmatically from say, a standard ABAP report?
We want the tests to run on a schedule and to be able to display the results pass/fail in a normal ABAP ALV list.
Note: we are not looking for a manual GUI (press Ctrl+Shift+F10) method but an ABAP program which runs unit tests of (potentially) other programs and classes.

The program RS_AUCV_RUNNER can be used to trigger ABAP Unit tests, among other possibilities.
Here are the selection parameters in the ABAP 7.40 version:

Email example:

Search the Web for more information.

The following ABAP report allows one to run one or more tests but this just calls the GUI and does not allow for programmatically receiving the results.
REPORT zmy_tests.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  DATA(objects) = VALUE sabp_t_tadir_keys( 
    ( obj_name = 'ZCL_MY_ABAP_CLASS1' obj_type = 'CLAS' )
    ( obj_name = 'ZCL_MY_ABAP_CLASS2' obj_type = 'CLAS' )
  ).
  CALL FUNCTION 'SABP_AU_TEST_ITEMS_FROM_IDE'
    EXPORTING
      tadir_keys    = objects
      with_coverage = 'X'.

